# what is the difference between Munin alert & Nagios alert

Tags: nagios, munin

What is the difference between `MuninAlert` and `NagiosAlert`? Does `NagiosAlert` has more features for `Alert` and is better than `MuninAlert` ? If so, kindly explain the `NagiosAlert` advantages over 'MuninAlert'!

Comment: How to send alert through munin?i tried many links.I could n't find out clear idea.Any one help me

Answer (score 2):

Munin is a networked resource monitoring tool that can help analyze resource trends and "what just happened to kill our performance?" problems. It is designed to be very plug and play. A default installation provides a lot of graphs with almost no work.

Nagios is a monitoring (alerting) tool. Munin could be a replacenment of Cacti. Nagios tell us in real time if something is wrong: like web server down, db load average, etc.

Using munin you can see the trends and the history about why that happenend.

Nagios will alert you (via email or SMS) when something is down and needs attention NOW.

Munin is for resource usage over time, and useful for things like: Varnish is not caching as much since so and so date, what did we change to cause that? Or, we now have increased CPU usage. Why is that? It allows you to compare day, week, month and past year. Nagios does not provide that, just alerts when thresholds are crossed.

But use both..

Comment: Hi tabasum, Thanks a lot for your replay but new version of munin also send the alert.My query is How(what way) Nagios alert is more flexible than munin.